# How to inject SQL Server physical files (.mdf .ldf) into reinstalled SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

By mistake I removed SQL Server 2012 Express Edition from my computer (Windows 10).

I have only copy of folders where SQL Server keeps files (`SQL` with subfolders `DATA`, `FTDATA`, `JOBS`, ...).

I want recover two databases where is few weeks of my work. Is it possible?

What I try to do:

- Reinstall MSSQL again on my computer and
- Create the same database name and replace files (`.mdf`/`.ldf` files). Doesn't work. Database is still visible as empty.
- Try to replace `DATA` folder - SQL Server services don't start
- Try to replace the whole `SQL` folder - SQL Server doesn't start

Is there any way to replace some files in that way I can read my database after it?

Comment: You need to [attach the databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190209.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to (re)create the database, but if you have the .mdf files, you will have to [attach the database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx).

Basically, you store the .mdf files you have retrieved from your previous system onto your new system and than follow the guidelines outlined in the above link. After that, your database will be back online.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it will be fine. I tested it on another database with sql 2012.

But in this situation i need to install sql 2016. My issue takes place during installing 2016 in upgrade mode, which failed. After that i want return to 2012, but database was already converted to 2016.

How to install 2016 if instalation fail - it will ba anoter question. But the first i try to find way by myself with some certificate isses during installin 2016.